# Trace of gamma matrices using FeynCalc

Tags: packages, feyncalc

I am using FeynCalc package in Mathematica to evaluate some complicated Dirac Traces, but as you know the default convention for the anticommutator of two Gamma matrices in this package is 
$$\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$$

I would like to change this convention to the one with a different sign on the right-hand side, i.e 
$$\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=-2\eta^{\mu\nu}$$
is there any way to do so in FeynCalc once for all?

Thanks